# VF page not displayed

Tags: visualforce

I have downloaded a managed package and there is one Custom tab, when I clicked on the custom tab, I should be able to the VF page overridden with the Standard layout. But I am unable to see the page in any browser. I tried it on my mobile and I am able to see the page. I granted access to the AppExchange product team which I had installed and they also said using my login they are able to see the page.

Could some one please suggest why I am not able  to see the page.

Answer (score 0):

If they can see it, it might be an external issue. Have you tried accessing it outside your company connection? Maybe try using your mobile phone?

Provided that they were really able to see the page using your login, this is not a permission problem.